# Фонетические словари транскрипций

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

Сейчас существует довольно много орфоэпических словарей русского языка, объясняющих произношение трудных слов. Однако существуют ли фонетические словари русского языка, содержание полные транскрипции слов (в рамках международного фонетического алфавита или кириллицей: то есть "космонавт" как [касманА'фт] или "достопримечательность" как [дастапр'им'ич'Ат'ил'нас'т'])? 
Или, возможно, существуют какие-нибудь алгоритмы/библиотеки, позволяющие производить фонетический разбор слова и его преобразование в транскрипцию согласно правилам русской фонетики? Либо же, ввиду неоднозначности правил выделения ударений, омографов и иных известных трудностей, такого в принципе быть не может?

Answer (score 1):

Я подобные словари искал, но в свободном доступе не нашел, а к монстрам ровня ABBYY после одной отповеди более соваться поостерёгся. Коммерческий подход... Интересно было бы посмотреть программы для чтения текстов вслух, но я туда не ходил.

Точных алгоритмов не может существовать в принципе, поскольку орфоэпический вид немалого количества слов определяется чисто словарным путём. Как автор программы "Ритм во мне", я столкнулся со схожей проблемой при построении словарей для поиска рифм ( http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/longr/slovari ). Решение было получено по принципу "безобразно, зато единообразно" и вылилось в алгоритм длиной порядка 400 строк на Delphi + базу в 43 стоки правил получения орфоэпического вида для гласных и 23 для согласных. Результатом я вполне удовлетворён, хотя посторонним людям показывать код постыдился бы  ;)